# Can't create a minimal chroot jail

Tags: linux, bash, debian, chroot

Was trying to create a minimal `chroot` jail.

The steps followed was:

1. Created a folder `chroot`
2. Copied bash to the folder `chroot`
3. Run `ldd bash` to know the dependencies

   ```
   ldd /bin/bash   linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff645e2000)
       libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f9155f75000)
       libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9155d71000)
       libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f91559e6000)
       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f91561bb000)
   ```
4. Then I created folder like

   ```
   ls chroot/

   bash  lib  lib64

   ls chroot/lib

   x86_64-linux-gnu
   ```
5. When I run

   ```
   chroot chroot/

   chroot: failed to run command `/bin/bash': No such file or directory
   ```

Comment: Put your bash to chroot/bin/

Comment: @RistoSalminen K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `chroot` tries to run `chroot/bin/bash` (`/bin/bash` inside `chroot`), but it is not able to run it because your `bash` is in `chroot/` (`/` inside `chroot`). Therefore the solution is to put your bash to `chroot/bin/`.